# angularjs subtract using $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am very new to not only asking for help but also using Angular so please bear with me.

Below is a copy of my calculator.js code that I am using to create a energy scale for light bulbs - I am currently stuck at the point where I want to show how much savings can be made against the other bulbs for example....

Halogen total - Incandescent total
hal_total - inc_total

Would someone please be so kind as to take a look at my code and maybe point me in the right direction.

```
    /* JavaScript Document */

    (function(){
    var app = angular.module('myCalculator',[]);

    app.controller('calculatorcontroller',['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.lumen_options = [375,600,900,1125,1600];
    $scope.current_lumens = 600;
    $scope.current_cost = 12;
    $scope.current_hours = 3;
    $scope.current_years = 1;
    $scope.current_bulbs = 1;
    $scope.total_days = 365;

    $scope.inc_conversion = .0625;
    $scope.hal_conversion = .0450;
    $scope.cfl_conversion = .0146;
    $scope.led_conversion = .0125;

    $scope.calculate = function(){

    $scope.inc_wattage = ($scope.current_lumens * $scope.inc_conversion).toFixed(1); 
    $scope.hal_wattage = ($scope.current_lumens * $scope.hal_conversion).toFixed(1);  
    $scope.cfl_wattage = ($scope.current_lumens * $scope.cfl_conversion).toFixed(1);  
    $scope.led_wattage = ($scope.current_lumens * $scope.led_conversion).toFixed(1); 

    if( $scope.current_hours > 24 ){ $scope.current_hours = 24 }

    var total_hours = $scope.total_days * $scope.current_hours;
    var total_total = $scope.total_days * $scope.current_hours * $scope.current_years * $scope.current_bulbs;
    var cost = $scope.current_cost / 100;

    $scope.inc_cost = ((($scope.inc_wattage * total_hours) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);
    $scope.hal_cost = ((($scope.hal_wattage * total_hours) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);
    $scope.cfl_cost = ((($scope.cfl_wattage * total_hours) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);
    $scope.led_cost = ((($scope.led_wattage * total_hours) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);

    $scope.inc_total = ((($scope.inc_wattage * total_total) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);
    $scope.hal_total = ((($scope.hal_wattage * total_total) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);
    $scope.cfl_total = ((($scope.cfl_wattage * total_total) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);
    $scope.led_total = ((($scope.led_wattage * total_total) / 1000) * cost).toFixed(2);

    }

    $scope.calculate();

    }]);    

    })();
```

Comment: Can you highlight the code that is not working?

Comment: Can't you just put something like `{{hal_total-inc_total}}` inside a `div` inside your controller in the html?

Comment: can you show your HTML code also?

Answer (score 0):

take this plnkr for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/9J3CIyoC06k45R0JJR4i?p=preview

one way you can display the computed difference is by calculating it inline in the template:

```
{{inc_total - hal_total}}
```

another useful piece when doing inline calculations is to utilize angular's number filter, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number; this code will display the calculated number with two decimal places:

```
{{inc_total - hal_total | number:2}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Cameron & Paul - this is exactly what I was looking for and as always I was looking at the most difficult solution to something that should be so easy - Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Cameron gave me the answer first off and then Paul very kindly offered the decimal place code, the simple answer was to add the following code within a div (or in my case a paragraph)....

{{inc_total - hal_total | number:2}}